# How to standardize multiple time series for GAN

Tags: time-series, standardization, gan

I have a set of 150 multivariate time series, each containing 10 variables measured at 50 time points. The goal is to generate artificial time series which are similar to the ones I have, so I trained a GAN. What is the correct way to standardize the time series the GAN is trained on? Without some form of standardization learning of the GAN will not really succeed I assume.

What I can do is calculating the mean and standard deviation of each time series for each feature separately and standardize using this. This way I can retain the correlation structure between time measurements. Is this a good way to go? If I do this how should I scale a GAN generated artificial time series back to the original domain? As I have 150 different means and sd per variable I don't know which to apply.